# Vote count click functionality is present without the privilege after loading new answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-count

When a user has the [established user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) privilege, they can click on the post score to see the individual counts for upvotes and downvotes.

When a user doesn't have this privilege this functionality isn't present, except after loading newly added answers without refreshing the page. After clicking the "new answers to this question" link the click functionality to view vote counts is added to all posts, though actually clicking on it results in a dialog stating that an error occurred (I'd assume due to not having the required reputation).

May be related to the fix for this previous bug report: [Vote count breakdown is unavailable on "new answers to this question" loaded after page load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128805/vote-count-breakdown-is-unavailable-on-new-answers-to-this-question-loaded-aft)

Comment: IIRC, the rationale for NOT showing vote breakdowns was the resource cost of computing it. Thus, if you already get that resource spent when loading newly added questions, you have not reason to NOT show it as the data is there?

Comment: @DVK I don't know about that, though I always assumed the calculation was done on a per post basis when the information was actually requested. From my point of view if you don't have the privilege to see that information you shouldn't be seeing anything remotely related to it (i.e. the post score shouldn't be clickable at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in build rev 2013.7.4.811.